# Measuring temperature of a solar object at different distances to its core

Tags: temperature, astronomy, universe, planets, sun

I recently was taught about the composition of the Sun, and that the temperature we know about it is its **surface temperature**. I find it hard to accept this.

There has to be a way in which temperature of a planet/object in space can be meausred as a function of the distance to said object's center?
Does anyone know of a method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It gets tricky trying to measure things we can't observe. ;) But we can estimate the temperature of stars at various depths using models that we have a high degree of confidence in.

Comment: Without being facetious with you, have you the same problem with the Earth's core?  There is a way, we estimate opacity, and convection rates, based on pretty well established methods.  If the core of the Sun changed temperature, not dramatically, but significantly for us here on Earth, how long would it take for us to notice?

Answer (score 2):

To some extent we can.

The surface of the sun we see in visible (or infrared) light is the radius at which the sun is dense enough that no photons can pass through. We can't see any deeper into the sun in visible light.

But further out from this surface is the corona - very hot gas which is spread out enough that visible photons go straight through it. It is too hot to see but can be seen in x-ray. So we can measure the temperature of this layer separately.

Inside the sun we can measure the temperature indirectly. Neutrinos are sub-atomic particles formed in the nuclear reactions inside the sun. They pass straight through the outer layers and we can detect them on Earth. The number/energy of these particles tell us about the physical details of the  nuclear reactions - including their temperature.